# How to obtain solid shape with adaptive threshold

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding, adaptive-threshold

Is it possible to get solid shape with adaptive threshold? In my case (A) I can only get hollow shape, but it seems like in some cases (B) it is possible to get solid shape. (see picture below)
[image]
What is the requirement of the input to achieve solid shape?

Below is my code for A

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_path = 'F:\\Coding Stuff\\Python\\Projects\\Open CV\\'
img = cv.imread(img_path + 'test_1.jpg')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11,2)
cv.imwrite('output.jpg', thresh)
```

Here is the input picture
[image]

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: @Tarik, thanks for the reply!  The images from case B are taken from Google search, and both of them are products of image processing softwares, so I don't have code for them.  

https://sites.google.com/site/qingzongtseng/adaptivethreshold 
http://www.roborealm.com/help/Adaptive_Threshold.php  

The code for case A is just a simple call to the function of cv2.adaptiveThreshold in Python. I'm in office now, and the Python script is in my personal PC, I will add it later.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post, but I think you can just detect the contours of the hollow shape and use polyfill to create a filled version of the detected shape.